# Visual Studio Python WPF debugging

Tags: python, wpf, visual-studio, ptvs

So I spend almost all of my programming time on Linux, but recently, for a project, I had to try out **PTVS** and **WPF**. As it is a very good framework, I would like to learn it further, but the issue in question is a huge disadvantage when compared to running python programs on Linux.
So say I have a little **WPF** project on **IronPython2.7**, with some buttons and some functions handling those buttons' click events. The problem is that **not every exception/error** present in that code **is shown in debugger**: sometimes it just says "the process exited with code 0x01". That, for example, happens if I try to access an array element outside of array bounds.
The question is: **is there a way to fix this and be able to see all the errors and exceptions while debugging a WPF program?**

Comment: Grab the IronPython sources and improve it to throw the correct error in you context?

Comment: @pix well it's a solution, but obviously not a simple one))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, IronPython projects in Visual Studio run using the managed debugger. This makes it really easy to debug mixed Python/.NET code, however, you don't get quite as nice an experience when you only have Python code.

To change this, right-click your project in Solution Explorer and select Properties. On the Debug tab, there's a dropdown for the launcher  - you can see a screenshot [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/PTVS/wiki/Debugging#launch-modes).

It's probably got `IronPython (.NET) launcher` selected, but changing it to `Standard Python launcher` should give you better pure-Python debugging. The downside is that you won't be able to step into .NET code anymore, and it's a little bit more invasive. In general though, the improvements are worth it if you are not using IronPython to extend a .NET application.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll check that out a little later and mark your answer as the solution if everything works :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it really helped to tweak the project debug settings